# "Send and archive" in Gmail using keyboard

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Starting recently (or I just didn't notice this earlier) you can send message, that you actually type, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. But (unfortunately?) this just sends the message without archiving it.

Is there any keyboard shortcut / equivalent for "Send and archive" in Gmail?

Comment: I think this changed recently. Would you confirm that CTRL+Enter does Send and Archive now? I'm now looking for a shortcut for send (without archive).

Comment: Confirmed. Ctrl+Enter no does Send and Archive. As per answer below I am pretty much sure that you can use Tab+Tab+Enter (or Space) to get Send only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick keyboard substitute for "Send and Archive" -- as noted by Paul Anderson on [this Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/+GuyKawasaki/posts/WhDVEtR8fi4) -- would be to press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (or <kbd>SPACE</kbd>).

As long as the "Send and Archive" button is enabled (**Settings > General > Send and Archive**) <kbd>TAB</kbd> will shift focus to the button and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> will select it.

Comment: Would be much better / more reasonable to get Ctrl+Enter to send message and Ctrl+Shift+Enter to send & archive it. But, hey, it's Google, right... Not many reasonable things around them...

Comment: @trejder That would be much better. Maybe someone can make a Gmail plugin or Chrome extension to do that.

Comment: I would like to see something like this https://www.gtricks.com/gmail/control-gmail-custom-shortcuts/ to allow general customization with this kind of function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Alfred which I highly recommend for every day workflows and tasks (it is Mac based) then you could use this workflow to replace CMD + Enter with Tab + Enter which does the trick perfectly.

[Alfred workflow Gmail Send and Archive](https://www.packal.org/workflow/gmail-send-and-archive-cmd-enter)